# Collision detection in STL's hash_map

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

I have to create a lookup table for C function names (as keys) to function pointers (as values). I am thinking of using STL's `hash_map` container, as the access time of a hash table is `O(1)`. Is there any good hash function for this? Currently I am using `(31*H + c)` as my hash function.

Also, does STL's `hash_map` takes care of collisions, or I have to take care of them in my code? Please give some examples if possible.

Sample Code I am currently working upon

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ext/hash_map>;

using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_cxx;

namespace __gnu_cxx {
#ifndef __HASH_STRING__
#define __HASH_STRING__
  template <>
    struct hash<string> {
      size_t operator() (const std::string& s) const
      {
        size_t h = 0;
        std::string::const_iterator p, p_end;
        for(p = s.begin(), p_end = s.end(); p != p_end; ++p)
        {
          h = 31 * h + (*p);
        }
        return h;
      }
    };
#endif
};

int main()
{
  hash_map<string, int> months;

  months["january"] = 1;
  months["february"] = 2;
  months["march"] = 3;
  months["april"] = 4;
  months["may"] = 5;
  months["june"] = 6;
  months["july"] = 7;
  months["august"] = 8;
  months["september"] = 9;
  months["october"] = 10;
  months["november"] = 11;
  months["december"] = 12;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function names as in keys? `hash_map` is an old implementation (by the way, the standard library has no has map/unordered map). Use a modern hash map, like boost's `unordered_map`. It has all the hashing stuff done, you just insert and continue your life. For what it's worth, `hash_map` would be pretty crappy if it didn't implement a hash map. :) (i.e.: yes, it should handle collisions, that's the job of a hash map.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got the full STL, it actually includes a hash function, `hash<T>`, which in its included form is [suitable for a few different key types](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html) including char* (C strings). I don't know details of its performance, but the STL is generally engineered to have acceptable performance for most applications.

As for collisions, that's for `hash_map` to deal with, you needn't worry about it.

Comment: what do you mean by full STL?  How I am going to check whether I got full STL or not? I have also added the sample code I am currently writing.

Comment: @Ravi: The STL is not part of the actual C++ standard (though a subset of it was incorporated into the C++ standard library). Bits of it have shown up with compilers from time to time, but often incomplete, sometimes in surprising ways. Since you seem to be working with GCC/g++, though, I can safely say you should have have `hash<T>`.

Comment: To clarify, C++ has a standard library. Saying "the STL" to mean "the standard library" is a misnomer. It could mean the standard library, the template parts of the standard library, the original STL, or something else. Ravi probably meant "the standard library", while I think Nicholas means "the SGI STL."

Comment: @GMan: I know STL is Standard Template Library which is a subset of standard C++ library.

Comment: @Ravi: That might be 'a' definition, but not 'the' definition. C++ does not define "STL" or "Standard Template Library".

Comment: @Nicholas: I don't think that my compiler has hash<T> because in the code posted above if I remove "size_t operator() (const std::string& s) const" function it gives compilation error 

/usr/include/c++/4.2/ext/hashtable.h:595: error: no match for call to "(const __gnu_cxx::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >) (const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)"

Comment: @Nicholas Knight & @GMan: There is actually a valid difference between the C++ standard and the STL here -- the C++ standard contains no `hash_map` class of any sort, so any talk about this class is specific to a particular implementation. (Note that even when hash data structures are incorporated into the next standard, they are called `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, etc, rather than `hash_X`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with collisions.  Also, I think std::hash is already defined, so you don't need to worry about a hash function.